# Simulink cannot solve the algebraic loop containing my homemade state space propagator

Tags: matlab, simulink

Since some coefficients of my state space model change over time, I made my own propagator for the state space matrices. In open loop (all inputs constant), all is fine. In closed loop though it runs only for a certain time (depending on the solver), then fails because of a so-called algebric loop it can't solve. By closed loop I mean 2 of the inputs being constants affected by noise (Tf and Ta), and the 3rd one is the output of a PID controller that monitors the output of this function. The discontinuities that Simulink is talking about may be P itself as it is a pulse width modulated signal (0 or 3000).

> Discontinuities detected within algebraic loop(s), may have trouble solving.
>
> Convergence problem when solving algebraic loop containing
> 'PAC_control_sim/BB/State space model' at time 5069.4509867718116.
> Simulink will try to solve this loop using Simulink 3 (R11) strategy.
>
> Simulink cannot solve the algebraic loop containing
> 'PAC_control_sim/BB/State space model' at time 5069.4509867718116
> using the TrustRegion-based algorithm due to one of the following
> reasons: the model is ill-defined i.e., the system equations do not
> have a solution; or the nonlinear equation solver failed to converge
> due to numerical issues.

Why? In the code below, I even replaced the time varying resistances (radiative term updated by the temperature gradients) by constants...

```
function [Tc, Ts] = stateSpaceModel(time, Tf, P, Ta)
coder.extrinsic('get_param')
coder.extrinsic('eval')

%States
persistent X_Tc; 
persistent X_Ts;

%Last call time
persistent lastTime;

%Physical values
%Radiative resistances in K^4/W (constant)
persistent Rsr;
persistent Rcr;
persistent Rar;
%Convective resistances in K/W (constant)
persistent Rsc;
persistent Rcc;
%Capacitances in J/K (constant)
persistent Cc;
persistent Cs;

%State space matrices (constant)
persistent C;
persistent D;

%Initial conditions
if isempty(X_Tc) 
    lastTime = double(0);
    
    %Retrieve the physical values
    Rsr = 0;
    Rsr = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Rshieldr'));
    Rcr = 0;
    Rcr = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Rcavityr'));
    Rar = 0;
    Rar = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Rambient'));
    Rcc = 0;
    Rcc = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Rcavity'));
    Rsc = 0;
    Rsc = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Rshield'));
    Cc = 0;
    Cc = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Ccavity'));
    Cs= 0;
    Cs = eval(get_param('PAC_control_sim/BB', 'Cshield'));
    
    %Initial state vector
    X_Tc = [0; 0;0; 0; 0; 0];
    X_Ts = X_Tc;
    
    %Build the constant matrices
    C = [1 0 1 0 1 0];
    D = [0 0 0];
end

%Build the input vector
U = [Tf;
     P;
     Ta];

%Calculate output & Ts (used for linearising thermal resistances)
Tc = C*X_Tc+D*U;
Ts = C*X_Ts+D*U;

%Update the thermal resistances (linearising radiative terms)
%Calculating parallel resistance with convective
%Rs = Rsc*Rsr/(Rsr+Rsc*abs(Tf-Ts)^3);
%Ditto for Rc
%Rc = Rcc*Rcr/(Rcr+Rcc*abs(Tc-Ts)^3);
%And Ra
%Ra = Rar/(abs(Ta-Tc)^3);
%Let's replace them instead by constants
Ra=Rar;
Rs=Rsc;
Rc=Rcc;

%Set the differential equations coeffs
alpha1=Rs*Cs*Rc*Cc;
alpha3s=Ra*Cc*Rc*Cs;
beta1=Rs*Cs*(Rc/Ra+1)+Cc*(Rs+Rc);
beta3s=Ra*Cc*(Rc/Rs+1)+Cs*(Ra+Rc);
gamma1=(Rs+Ra+Rc)/Ra;
gamma3s=(Ra+Rs+Rc)/Rs;
delta1=1;
delta3s=1;
alpha2=alpha1;
beta2=beta1;
gamma2=gamma1;
delta2=Rs;
alpha3=Ra*Cs*Cc*Rc;
alpha2s=Rs*Cc*Cs*Rc;
beta3=Ra*(Cc*(1+Rc/Rs)+Cs*(Rc/Ra+1));
beta2s=Rs*(Cs*(1+Rc/Ra)+Cc*(Rc/Rs+1));
gamma3=Ra/Rs*(Rc/Ra+1)+1;
gamma2s=Rs/Ra*(Rc/Rs+1)+1;
delta3=1+Rc/Rs;
delta2s=(1+Rc/Ra)*Rs;
alpha1s=alpha2s;
beta1s=beta2s;
gamma1s=gamma2s;
delta1s=delta2s/Rs;

%Build the time varying matrices
A_Tc=[0                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0;
     -gamma1/alpha1     -beta1/alpha1      0                  0                  0                  0;
     0                  0                  0                  1                  0                  0;
     0                  0                  -gamma2/alpha2     -beta2/alpha2      0                  0;
     0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  1;
     0                  0                  0                  0                  -gamma3/alpha3     -beta3/alpha3];
 
A_Ts=[0                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0;
     -gamma1s/alpha1s   -beta1s/alpha1s    0                  0                  0                  0;
     0                  0                  0                  1                  0                  0;
     0                  0                  -gamma2s/alpha2s   -beta2s/alpha2s    0                  0;
     0                  0                  0                  0                  0                  1;
     0                  0                  0                  0                  -gamma3s/alpha3s   -beta3s/alpha3s];
 
B_Tc=[0             0                   0;
     delta1/alpha1  0                   0;
     0              0                   0;
     0              delta2/alpha2       0;
     0              0                   0;
     0              0                   delta3/alpha3];
 
B_Ts=[0             0                   0;
     delta1s/alpha1s 0                  0;
     0              0                   0;
     0              delta2s/alpha2s     0;
     0              0                   0;
     0              0                   delta3s/alpha3s];
 
%If last time exists
if ~isnan(lastTime)
    %Calculate change of state
    X_Tcdot = A_Tc*X_Tc+B_Tc*U;
    X_Tsdot = A_Ts*X_Ts+B_Ts*U;
    %Update internal state
    X_Tc = X_Tc+X_Tcdot*double(time-lastTime);
    X_Ts = X_Ts+X_Tsdot*(time-lastTime);
end

%Update last time
lastTime = time;
```

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but Algebraic Loops typically occur when you're using the output of a function and feeding it back into the function in the same time step (i.e. without any delays). It looks like you might be doing the same thing here. Again, this has nothing to do with the code _inside_ your block, just the input and output signals.

Using a Unit Delay block at the input ports or a Memory block (if your solver is continuous instead of discrete) should solve the problem.

Comment: Solved it, thanks! I didn't think about it because I already had a zero order hold, but apparently unit delays work but not holds. If you wish to post an answer I'll accept it.